# Why does pstricks have an effect on tikz' draw opacity when used within beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex, pstricks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
        \node[on chain] {A};
        \node[on chain,join={with chain-1 by {draw opacity=0}}] {B};
        \node[on chain,join={with chain-2 by {draw opacity=1}}] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces `A-B-C`. If I comment out `\usepackage{pstricks}` or use the `article` document class, then it produces `A B-C`, the correct result. Why is that and how can I use pstricks together with tikz and beamer in this case?

Edit: I use pdflatex.

Comment: Which engine do you use to compile your document?

Comment: With `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`, the result is correct.

Comment: I use pdflatex.

Comment: You cannot use `pstricks` from `pdflatex`

Comment: JLDiaz: Sure, with `-shell-escape` and `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. But my problem also occurs without this, so I didn't include it.

Comment: @neo If you use `pdflatex` with `pstricks`, you get some warnings about `Non-PDF special ignored!`...

Answer (score 2):

run it with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. Then you also do not need the package `auto-pst-pdf`. However, I suppose a problem with beamers opacity settings.

Comment: `xelatex` takes 1min 6s to compile my slides. Then I rather use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` which takes 9s.