# Semi-transparent Tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

Trying to reproduce the semi-transparent fill from the answer to my previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188453/37570 I cannot get it to work. Tried adding `backgrounds` library inside `ifpdf` and outside of it, but the fill is still solid with no transparency.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\ifpdf
    \usepackage{forest}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\else
    \usepackage{pst-barcode}
\fi

\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l r}
&
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{pspicture}(1.02in,1.02in)
    \psbarcode{http://localhost/Chart}{version=5}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{adjustbox} \\
 & \\ % extra row for vertical separation
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    draw=black, align=center, l sep=4ex, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    node options={font=\scriptsize, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex},
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-2ex) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where n children=0{
        child anchor=west,
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            ([xshift=-6em]!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for parent={
            parent anchor=south, l sep=-12em, grow'=east, calign=child edge%, draw=blue         
        } %,draw=red
    }{}, base=b,
    fill=white!25,
    fill opacity=.75,
}
[\textbf{Aaaaaa  Aaaaa}\\
Aa. Aaaaaaaaaaaa \\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\Aaaaaaaaaaa 
,name=10003863
    [\textbf{Bbbbbb Bbbbbbb}\\
Bbbbbb Bbbbbbbbb Bbbbbbbb\\Bbbbbbbbbbb 
,name=10004145
        [\textbf{Cc Cccccc}\\
Ccccccccc Ccccccccccccc Ccccccc\\Ccccccccccc 
,name=10003046,node options={dashed}
[,phantom, minimum height=1ex]
    [\textbf{Dddddd Ddddddd}\\
Ddddddddddddd Dddddddddd\\Ddddddddddd 
,name=10004047,node options={dashed}]
]
    [\textbf{Eeeeee Eeeee}\\
Eeeeeeeee Eeeeeeeeeee\\Eeeeeeeeeee 
,name=10004057,node options={dashed}[,phantom]]
]]
 %
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize, align=center, draw=black!20, minimum width=14em, minimum height=10ex, rounded corners=1ex}}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[->,dashed] (10004047) to (10004145);
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=south,draw=black](10011144) at ([xshift=16em]10004145 |- 0,-18ex) {
\textbf{Fffffff Fffff}\\
Ffffffffff\\fff fff\\Ffffff Fffffffffffffff
}[];
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[->,dashed] (10004145) to (10011144);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[->,dashed] (10003046) to (10003863);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[->,dashed] (10004057) to (10003863);
\end{scope}
 %
\end{forest}
} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it have something to do with the difference that you are filling in white?  Does the output change if you change that?

Comment: No, color does not matter - it is the difference between the MWE and linked answer that are escaping me.

Comment: It's the `auto-pst-pdf` package.  Commenting it and the `pspicture` environment out gives you a semitransparent fill.  Work your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/1402) down so that it has just these two features in it (no table, no forest, etc) and it might get some more attention.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121927/1402

Comment: That's a good enough answer for me for now! Appreciate your help. However, Forest is the whole point of doing this exercise.

Comment: @ajeh Yes, but if you want to use `forest` with `auto-pst-pdf` etc., you want to solve this problem. And that will be easier to solve if you pare things down to the essentials. That is, the point of your document may be the tree. But the point of your MWE is to solve the problem and `forest` is irrelevant there. (Cf. the point of my document is to discuss the tradition of Y Fari Lwyd and I want to be able to write `tŷ` in order to do so. The problem I face concerns the use of `ŷ`. My MWE need not (and should not) involve a bunch of stuff about Y Fari Lwyd.)